# InfoPath form/List for a site still using SharePoint2007 interface inside SharePoint2010 environment. (timeline sensitive)

Tags: infopath, master-page, custom-list, branding, feature-upgrade

We recently completed a SharePoint 2007-2010 Migration last year. We have some sites that are using custom branding, and we've kept these sites using the 07 interface in order to prevent any broken pages/code.

There was a project recently to create a new SharePoint List with InfoPath design, and we now have a template to use that's using the 2010 interface (version 4). So this InfoPath form was created based off a sharepoint 2010 list.

--- The problem is, this list template is supposed to be housed on a SharePoint site that's still utilizing the old interface, as well as with custom branding, so a straight visual upgrade will not be possible, nor approved at this time, (and this list needs to replace a currently broken process, so this is time sensitive.)

How can we go about implementing this InfoPath/SharePoint 2010 list template without visually upgrading the entire site? Can I visually upgrade just the page that displays the list? If I visually upgrade the entire site, I'm sure that pages will be broken, the site's custom branding will need to be reworked for use on the 2010 interface, and we'll have more problems than the new list solves just trying to implement it.

I'm aware that housing it on a subsite would work, but if there's a way to avoid creating a subsite, we would much rather that. (I'm assuming that searching for the content created from the new list would be hindered or more difficult with an additional subsite.)

Comment: I have access to SharePoint designer, I don't know enough about .NET to change anything, was hoping for a little advice, or things to try. I will look on the infopath side of things, to see if i can port over the form to a SharePoint 2007 compliant form.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just sent the list to a different site on the intranet. Question still remains as it's still valid for someone that may encounter the same issue eventually and searches for similar criteria.

would be interested to see if someone could duplicate the issue and come up with a real solution. I urge someone to try it out sometime and see what they can come up with..